# Extending a core class in rails plugin is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, minitest

Inside of `#PLUGIN/lib/#PLUGIN` I inserted the following:

```
String.class_eval do
  def to_squawk
    "squawk! #{self}".strip
  end
end
```

And when I try to test in Rails Console. I get the following error: `NoMethodError: undefined method`to_squawk' for "test string":String`

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0.beta2)
2.1.3 :001 > "test string".to_squawk
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_squawk' for "test string":String
  from (irb):1
  from /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
  from /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
  from /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
  from /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am following the tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

**Does anyone know what the problem is here?**

Comment: Can someone try the code in the rails guide. Simple three steps and let me know if its working for you. I tried this on 2 machines and I get the same flawed output. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html ++Thanks!

Comment: I know this was two years ago, but did you ever resolve this? I am running into the same problem. Seems crazy that the Rails docs could be flat out wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code in the Rails Guide:

```
String.class_eval do
  def to_squawk
    "squawk! #{self}".strip
  end
end
```

This is your code:

```
String.class_eval do
  def self.to_squawk
    "squawk! #{self}".strip
  end
end
```

See the difference? The Guide's code defines an instance method that instances of String respond to (i.e. `"foo".to_squawk # => "squawk! foo"`), but your code with its stray `self` defines a class method that the String class responds to (i.e. `String.to_squawk # => "squawk! String"`).

Comment: Sorry thanks for pointing that out. I didn't mean to have `self` there it was just something I was trying. It actually doesn't work either way. I copied the code step for step and I did it on two machines and it doesn't work.

Comment: this question is continuation to an issue started from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473190/is-this-minitest-output-normal-it-looks-horrendous (thanks for helping)

Comment: No I did not. I tried multi versions of Ruby and 2 machines and I still have this problem. Getting past MiniTest -- I tried to see if the class method worked in console and thats when I realized it wasn't working. Something is wrong internally. I think it's a bug...

Comment: I just went through steps 1–3 in the Rails Guide and it worked just fine (using 4.1.6, the latest stable Rails). Are you sure you're in the right directory? You need to be in the `yaffle` directory when you run `rake` and `yaffle/test/dummy` when you run `bin/rails console`. Since you're using RVM you might need to use `bundle exec`, but I'm not an RVM user so I can't say for sure.

Comment: This is crazy yes - I'm in the right dir. I'm guessing its a Rails 4.2.0.beta2 release issue. I will try 4.1.6